# Building a house, door from house to garage

Tags: doors

We are building a house and they installed the garage door to open towards the garage with two steps down, I don't think is right and I asked them to flip it but now they say it was that way in the plans, and I should pay for it. I am not sure is fair, and definitely not safe. We are in Edmond Oklahoma and I cannot find the code. Could someone please help me with that? Thanks

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by flip it;Change the door to open inward ? Your concern I am guessing is the steps. Your county building department / inspector can say if it violates code. Generally there is NO CODE regarding which way the door opens. If it violates code they fix it regardless of the plans. If not a violation its in the plans you approved when you signed and said build it. If this is a PUD builder you might have recourse with them;see their management. If its a build my custom home from my selected plan; you might have no recourse but to blame yourself, details, experience.

Comment: Voting to close. It's not at all clear what the question is asking, but it seems to lean toward legal/contractual.

Answer (score 2):

Doors cannot swing out over a stair without a landing. (See IBC Code, Paragraph R311.3.2.) Take it to your local Building Official and ask for, "an interpretation ". There's an exemption, but I don't think it applies to you.